# 10 ties in a wardrobe

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have $10$ ties in a wardrobe and I pick one at random with probability $0.1$ each day independently. I return the tie after usage, so we allow replacement.

let $\,\theta$ be equal to the number of ties I used in course of $5$ days. what is the expected value and variance of $\, \theta$ random variable?

Now , I know this is some type of  application of indicators, I would like to know which theorem or method in regards to the indicators does this problem use for the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the theory.

Suppose we let
$$X_i=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if tie i is used at least once in 5 days} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
for $i=1,2,3,\dots,10$. Then we will have
$$\theta = \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i$$
so by linearity of expectation
$$E(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} E(X_i)$$
Note: The theorem that $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ does *not* require that $X$ and $Y$ be independent.  That's good for us here, because the $X_i$'s are not independent.  So the problem of finding the expected value of $\theta$ reduces to finding the expected value of $X_i$, which seems simpler, and since $X_i$ is either zero or one, we have $E(X_i) = P(X_i=1)$.

Finding the variance of $\theta$ is a little more complicated, and to apply the method of indicators we will need to find $E(X_i X_j)$ for $i < j$.  (Don't make the mistake of thinking $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i)\cdot E(X_j)$ here!)  Assuming we can find $E(X_i X_j)$, recall that 
$$var(\theta) = E(\theta^2) - E(\theta)^2$$
We already know how to find $E(\theta)$, so it remains to find $E(\theta^2)$.  To do so, we apply the identity
$$ \left( \sum_{n=1}^{10} X_i \right)  ^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{10} X_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i <j} X_i X_j$$
In our case $X_i$ is always either zero or one, so $X_i^2 = X_i$, hence
$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^{10} X_i \right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{10} X_i + 2 \sum_{i <j} X_i X_j$$
Again applying linearity of expectation,

$$E(\theta^2)=E \left[ \left( \sum_{n=1}^{10} X_i \right)^2 \right] = \sum_{n=1}^{10} E(X_i) + 2 \sum_{i <j} E(X_i X_j)$$
We assume we know how to find all the quantities on the right-hand side of the above equation, so we can find $E(\theta^2)$, which is the last step we need in finding $var(\theta)$.

Comment: So the expectation is $10$ * $(1 - (X_{i}^5)^{c}) = 10 * (1 - (\frac{9}{10})^{5}) = 4$?

Comment: The last expression on the RHS in the last line is found by exclusion inclusion formula of its complement?

Comment: @Fred No, inclusion/exclusion has nothing to do with the final equation.  The final equation is the result of taking the expectation of both sides of the previous equation and applying the theorem about linearity of expectation.  However, in finding $P(X_i=1)$, for example, you may find it easier to find $P(X_i=0)$ and work from there.